# Change class name in Wordpress wp_list_page nav

Tags: wp-list-pages

I'm using Wordpress's wp_list_pages to display a nav of pages on the site.

Some pages have children so I need a dropdown menu below those links.

The html is something like this

```
<ul class="">
    <li class="page_item page-item-6 current_page_item"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-6 current_page_item"><a href="/">Profile</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-8 page_item_has_children dropdown">
        <a href="">Products &#038; Services</a>
        <ul class='children'>
            <li class="page_item page-item-17"><a href="">Buying</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-19"><a href="">Selling</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-23"><a href="">Managing</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I wanted to use bootstrap to create the nav and dropdown menus.

Something like - http://www.ttmt.org.uk/nav/

The html for this is something like this.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Messages <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Drafts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sent Items</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

I need to add a 'dropdown' class the li and ul containing the child pages. I also need to add a class and a data-toggle attribute to the 'a' tag.

How can I add these clases when I using wp_list_pages and the nav is created dynamically.

I'm using this function to add 'dropdown' to li containin the child pages

```
function add_parent_class( $css_class, $page, $depth, $args ){
    if ( ! empty( $args['has_children'] ) )
        $css_class[] = 'dropdown';
    return $css_class;
}
add_filter( 'page_css_class', 'add_parent_class', 10, 4 );
```

How could I extened this function add the other classes I need

Comment: you may have better luck using the `'walker'` argument of `wp_list_page`

Comment: here's a bootstrap walker class for `wp_nav_menu` - I imagine you could use this for `wp_list_page` with only a little modification required, if any: https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker